# Why are all my agents female?

Tags: java, repast-simphony

I have 10 generic agents:

```
public class Agent {
    private Context<Object> context;
    private Geography<Object> geography;
    public int id;
    public boolean isFemale;
    public double random;


public Agent(Context<Object> context, Geography<Object> geography, boolean isFemale, double random) {
    this.context = context;
    this.geography = geography;
    this.isFemale = isFemale;
    this.random = random;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isFemale() {
    return isFemale;
}

public void setFemale(boolean isFemale) {
    this.isFemale = isFemale;
}

public double getRandom() {
    return random;
}

public void setRandom(double random) {
    this.random = random;
}

public void methods  {

... does things
}
```

The agents are created in a geography context (latitude and longitude). I am trying to construct my agents as randomly male or female. The code that I am using in the context builder to create the agents is below:

```
    Agent agent = null;
    boolean isFemale = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double random = RandomHelper.nextDoubleFromTo(0, 1);
        if (random > 0.33){
            isFemale = true;
        }
        agent = new Agent(context, geography, isFemale, random);
        context.add(agent);
        Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(-79.6976, 43.4763);
        Point geom = fac.createPoint(coord);
        geography.move(agent, geom);
    }
```

When I test the code, I am getting that they are all female. What am I doing wrong? If anything I would think that they would all be male since booleans are by default false.

Comment: And what does `RandomHelper.nextDoubleFromTo(0, 1);` do?  Besides, what's wrong with `Random#nextBoolean`?

Comment: How many `double`s are there between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I changed it to 0 when I was testing it. I was trying to see if I could make them all male. I will change it back to the original.

Comment: @LinuxNoob1337 The OP has changed his code since the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `boolean` not updating for every iteration once it becomes `isFemale = true` it remains true for other values.You can add else part to set it `false`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        isFemale = false;//Set it here
        double random = RandomHelper.nextDoubleFromTo(0, 1);
        if (random > 0.33){
            isFemale = true;
            //...
```

***OR***

```
if (random > 0.33){
   isFemale = true;
} else {
   isFemale = false;
}
```

***OR***

```
agent = new Agent(context, geography, random > 0.33, random);
```

Comment: or `isFemale = random > 0.33`

Answer (score 1):

because once your boolean is set to true it stays that way ( you never set it to false, it is only one branch of if).

BTW, catching question title